# Getting item order options to display

Tags: adminhtml

I am customizing the back end of a store and need to display the field of custom text that is printed on each product in an order

i tried

```
<?php $orderq = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId); $itemsq
= $orderq->getAllVisibleItems(); foreach ($itemsq as $itemq):
    $optionsq = $itemq->getProductOptions();
    foreach ($optionsq as $optionq):
           echo $optionq;
    endforeach; endforeach; ?>
```

and it does not work is there a different ->get to output the info?